# user-defined markup aliases with l3

Tags: expl3, key-value, semantics

I would like to write a package providing semantic markup for scholarship in the humanities (loosely following TEI-XML). In the source code, users would use macros like `\term` for a foreign term or `\socalled` for "scare quotes".

I would like to provide a default set of typesetting commands that each of these macros would expand to (`\term` -> `\emph`, `\socalled` -> `\enquote`). **I would also like provide a simple key-value interface for the user to reconfigure these** (for example, to meet a publisher's specifications). And, for future robustness and flexibility I would like to do it in `expl3` or at least using `xparse`. (I must admit I am completely baffled by `expl3` but I'm hoping to learn something here.)

I have gotten as far as a `\setTagFormat` command that creates a new command aliasing the markup tag to its typesetting macro. **How could I do this with a key-value interface such as `l3keys`?**

In the current version (MWE below) the user must enter a command like `\setTagFormat{\term}{\emph}` for each tag. So perhaps an interface like this would be better:

```
\setSemanticTagFormat{                                                                                                                 
  \term = \emph                                                                                                                      
  \q = \enquote                                                                                                                      
}
```

In an alternate approach, since many tags will be aliased to the same typesetting commands (basically italics or quotation marks), you could go in the other direction:

```
\setSemanticTagFormat{                                                                                                               
   \emph = \term, \mentioned, \foreign, \worktitle                                                                                    
   \enquote = \q, \socalled, \parttitle                                                                                               
}
```

It also occurs to me that (going back toward plain TeX) I could just do this:

```
\let\term\emph
\let\q\enquote
```

Here is a working but not ideal example with `xparse` but not `l3keys`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\setTagFormat{m m}{%                                                                                                 
  \NewDocumentCommand #1{m}{#2{##1}}%                                                                                                   
}
\setTagFormat{\term}{\emph}
\setTagFormat{\q}{\enquote}                                                                                                                

\begin{document}

\term{Musica ficta} is the practice of adding accidentals where they are not notated.
The teacher told us, \q{Always sing F-sharp before a cadence on G!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use single letter aliases!!!

Comment: @cfr `<q>` is the TEI-XML tag for quotations, and I had originally hoped to stay close to their element names. But they also use `<l>` for poetic line which I find unacceptable.

Comment: Do you plan also to support LaTeX to Tei conversion? Tei is supported by tex4ht, it would be easy to add support for this markup

Comment: @michal.h21 Yes, the idea was to create a syntax that could be easily converted to TEI or to other formats, possibly using `tex4ht`  (humanities publishers still want `.doc` files for submission).

Comment: @AndrewCashner I've already created configuration file which will automatically configure macros created with Egreg's method for TEI output using tex4ht. It shouldn't be hard to configure it for `.odt` output as well, which can be converted to `.doc` easily

Comment: @michal.h21 This is promising, thanks! Now I just need to learn expl3, tei-xml, and tex4ht...

Comment: @AndrewCashner I've put everything to [Gist](https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/6104f70091e0f4fead36). compile `sample.tex` with `make4ht -c hello.cfg sample.tex`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A little bit simpler with `\keyval_parse:NNn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \cashner_make_semantic:Nn
  {
    \tl_map_inline:nn {#2} % for every token in the second argument,
      { \NewDocumentCommand ##1 {} {#1} } % create the alias to the first
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \NewSemanticMarkup { m }
  % with keyval syntax,
  % |          / ignore single keys
  % |         |     \           /  and apply our function
  % |         |      \         /  /                      \ to our argument
  { \keyval_parse:NNn \use_none:n \cashner_make_semantic:Nn {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{csquotes}

\NewSemanticMarkup {
  \textit = \term,
  \enquote = \scare \socalled
}

\begin{document}
hi

\term{hi}

\scare{hi}

\socalled{hi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good one, I didn't know about it. I had to make things a little bit more complicate because l3keys `\detokenize`s the key name so I had to remove ``\`` plus the non gobbled spaces. By the way, shouldn't you use `\use_none:n` rather than `\use:n`?

Comment: @Manuel I was wondering what all that was about! :) `\keyval_parse:` comes in *real* handy.

Comment: @SeanAllred This is great! When you get a chance it would be helpful if you could add a little explanation of what these few lines of code are doing. The `expl3` concepts are so new to me that I really have no idea what is going on.

Comment: @AndrewCashner see edit :)

Comment: Would it work with @Manuels syntax as well? I think `\enquote={\aa,\bb,\cc}` might be an easier to understand syntax than `\enquote=\aa\bb\cc` (I guess it would need a test to see if something is a comma separated list or not.

Comment: @daleif look through the edit history ;)

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks! It will still be next year before I really understand all this (`:Nnn` etc.)

Comment: @AndrewCashner read `texdoc expl3` – it's a life-saver

Comment: I probably should not have asked the question since I realize now I am not really equipped to judge the answers. I may just stick with `\let` until I have a reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

I'd avoid grouping macros that should be equivalent to some other macro, because this will make harder changing the meaning: if they are a large number, they'll be difficult to spot in the groups.

A line for each equivalence seems better, and easier to manage for changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \SetSemanticMarkup { m }
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \SetEquivalent{ ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetEquivalent}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{=}} m }
 {
  \cashner_set_equivalent:nn #1
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \cashner_set_equivalent:nn
 {
  \cs_new_eq:NN #1 #2
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{csquotes}

\SetSemanticMarkup {
  \term = \textit,
  \scare = \enquote,
  \socalled = \enquote,
  \q = \enquote,
}

\begin{document}
hi

\term{hi}

\scare{hi}

\socalled{hi}

\term{Musica ficta} is the practice of adding accidentals where they are not notated.
The teacher told us, \q{Always sing F-sharp before a cadence on G\@!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic, but I'm curious: how does the `\@` before `!` affect the end-of-sentence rubber after `"`?

Comment: @SeanAllred So that the correct space factor is set after `G`.

Comment: As in the space between the G and the !? I though that macro affected space *after* the next token?

Comment: @SeanAllred The space factor code of `G` is 999, which means that `!` will set the space factor to 1000 instead of 3000.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! What advantage would this have over `\let\term\emph` and so on?

Comment: @AndrewCashner Easier syntax, not much more.

Comment: Even so, this would be vastly simplified with `\NewDocumentCommand \SetSemantic {m} { \keyval_parse:NNn \use_none:n \cs_set_eq:NN {#1} }` (ignoring the fact that each `N` will be getting a braced argument`).

Comment: @SeanAllred I wouldn't abuse the key-value system.

Comment: ? Do you consider using a long-standing, documented, public function 'abuse'?